# Embed GMF generated editor into MasterDetailsBlock?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gmf

The canonical way to use the MasterDetailsBlock of the Eclipse Forms API is to use a table or tree viewer as master view. Has anyone ever attempted to use a GMF generated graphical editor as master view? I've got a rather complex multipage editor that already uses Eclipse Forms for many pages, but I still have to drag the properties view along only for the graphical editor. I'd like to get rid of this by embedding the graphical editor into a MasterDetailsBlock and taking care of the property handling myself within the details block.